# WPF - Dynamically add button next to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating Label, Textbox and a button dynamically. I need Button to appear in the same line as textbox to its right.

This is the code i am using:

```
    Label lbl = new Label()
    {
        Content = "Some Label",
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        Height = 28,
    };

    TextBox tb = new TextBox()
    {
        Text = "Some Text",
        IsReadOnly = true,
    };

    Button btn = new Button()
    {
        Content = "Click Me",
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
        Margin = new Thickness(tb.ActualWidth),
    };
```

I am assigning Button Margin to the Right of TextBox but it still appears in the next line under the textbox.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `StackPanel` to solve your problem:

```
StackPanel spMain = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };

Label lbl = new Label()
  {
      Content = "Some Label",
      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
      HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
      VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
      Height = 28,
  };

StackPanel spInner = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

TextBox tb = new TextBox()
{
    Text = "Some Text",
    IsReadOnly = true,
};

Button btn = new Button()
{
    Content = "Click Me",
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    Margin = new Thickness(tb.ActualWidth),
};

spInner.Children.Add(tb);
spInner.Children.Add(btn);

spMain.Children.Add(lbl);
spMain.Children.Add(spInner);
```

You can check following link for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.orientation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the page content that you are placing the controls on is, is it a grid or something else?

Why not also create a stackpanel which will properly contain your items in the fashion as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you place all the created controls in a StackPanel with its Orientation set to Horizontal. This way they will always placed next to eachother.

```
var stPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
var button = new Button() { ... }
stPanel.Children.Add(button);
//And so on
```

**Edit:** kmatyaszek was ahead of me... :)

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be better if you use the Content methode from the instance of Button

```
 private byte _count;
    internal void FillbtnSubCat(Grid grid)
    {
        var myDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
        var myButton = new Button();
        var myBlock = new TextBlock()
        {
            TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
            Text = "Some Text",
            Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10)
        };

        Grid.SetColumn(myButton, _count);
        myButton.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 25);
        myButton.MinWidth = 30;

        myButton.Content = myBlock;

        myDefinition.Width = new GridLength(68);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(myDefinition);
        grid.Children.Add(myButton);
        _count++;
    }
```

XAML

```
 <Grid Name="Grid1" Height="100" Width="auto">

            </Grid>
```